# Retrive stats app install Play Store Google API in PHP

Tags: php, api, installation, google-api-php-client

I'm working on a back office feature it retrieve all monthly app installations stats. I'd like to use an API to automatize it. I'm currently looking for the Google API storage. I found that to get monthly reports : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en#export
They only explain how doing that in Python.
I don't have any idea to do that in PHP.

I wrote in a test_call.php file :

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../libs/googleAPI/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("NAME");
$client->setDeveloperKey("KEY");
```

I don't see how to proceed now.
Thanks for your answers.

Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience working with the Storage API; Nevertheless, if all you are looking for is an example of how to use the PHP Client library to get bucket objects (such as the monthly reports) then you might want to try using this code:

```
<?php session_start(); 

//INCLUDE PHP CLIENT LIBRARY
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../libs/googleAPI/vendor/autoload.php';

$scopes = array(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only"
);

// Create client object
$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/test_call.php');
$client->setAuthConfig("client_credentials.json");
$client->addScope($scopes);    

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  $service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);

  $request = $service->objects->listObjects("bucket-myfirstbucket");

  $objects = $request->getItems();

  foreach ($objects as $item) {    

    echo $item->id."<br><br>";

  }


} else if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {

  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

} else {

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/test_call.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

}


?>
```

Please note this implementation is not done with the use of a service account like how [this document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en#export) explains. If you would like to perform an implementation using a service account then please refer to [this document](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts).

Comment: Do you need to have an "Premium" Google Storage account to do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Premium" but if what you mean is if you have to pay for this... YES. You can also purchase a support package here https://cloud.google.com/support/ and get support from Cloud Platform Support team.

Comment: Okay thanks for all your informations ! I just tried it. I paid for a Google Cloud Storage and it's work well :). So I print the contents of a bucket. Now I'll try to find how to retrieve apps stats install. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain another side of my question. With the Morfinismo's code, I can print my bucket and my files from the **Google Cloud Storage**.

Now, I'd like to retrieve **Google Play** statistics reports with a PHP script and save them into my Google Cloud Storage. How can I do that ?
Today, I can access theses stats from the `Google Play Console > Reports`

Is there a method to download reports ? I found something to access them but only with gsutil.

The following line is the stat report file name variable in my code.

```
$report_to_download = ‘installs/installs_com.example.com_201610__app_version.csv’;
```

Is it possible ?